# Cambiar el namespace por defecto de un xml de entrada de un servicio soap en C#

Tags: c#, xml, soap, namespace

Tengo un servicio soap cuyo servicio soap generé con la herramienta XSD desde la terminal de VS, la parte inicial del codigo que no incluyo completo por ser muy largo es este:

```
namespace ServicioBanred.Models.Entrada.Transferencia
{
using System.Xml.Serialization;


/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.8.3928.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08.031")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08.031", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Document : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeader
{


    private HeaderData headerField;
    
    private FIToFICustomerCreditTransferV06 fIToFICstmrCdtTrfField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public HeaderData Header {
        get {
            return this.headerField;
        }
        set {
            this.headerField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    public FIToFICustomerCreditTransferV06 FIToFICstmrCdtTrf {
        get {
            return this.fIToFICstmrCdtTrfField;
        }
        set {
            this.fIToFICstmrCdtTrfField = value;
        }
    }

}
```

Y que luego uso como dato de entrada en el servicio asmx creado, asi:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// Para permitir que se llame a este servicio web desde un script, usando ASP.NET AJAX, quite la marca de comentario de la línea siguiente. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Transferencia : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    public Entrada.Document cabeceraConsulta = new Entrada.Document();
    
    [WebMethod]
    [SoapHeader("cabeceraConsulta")]
    public Salida.Document Consulta()
    {
                   
        Salida.Document mensajeSalida = new Salida.Document();



        return mensajeSalida;
    }
}
```

El problema que tengo es que en el xml proporcionado por el proveedor, se ve de esta forma el namespace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pgim:Document xmlns:pgim="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.06.031"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.06.031 pacs.008.031.xsd ">
```

Mientras que el mio al ejecutar el servicio se ve asi:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
```

Mi duda es como hag para cambiar el namespace por defecto a pgim?